# Primeng chart - how to remove the color square from label?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, bar-chart, primeng

I'm using PrimeNg chart.

```
this.chartData = {
        labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'CHARTS TITLE - HOW TO REMOVE THE ORANGE BLOCK HERE?',
            backgroundColor: ['#FF9900', '#FF3300', '#DDDDDD', '#474747', '#777777', '#CC3300'],
            data: [29, 29, 26, 11, 18, 12]
          }
        ]
      }; ....
```

I'm trying to remove the orange square next to title or change it to white. [See the image of my chart here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DvjA.png)
The title (lable) must stay.
Is it possible?
(The graph columns must stay as in the picture.)